# lock divs of webpage & focus at single div

Tags: javascript, jsp

how to set focus at one div (div id =rotate) and lock the other divs in the web page until the work of that div is completed?? rotate div  contains an image which rotates until the data is extracted from database? I have to prevent the user from doing other works in the webpage until data is extracted from db and displayed @ another div (div id= display_db)?

**pseudocode:**

```
while(clicked on div id = rotate )
lock other divs of webpage and,

div id = rotate
    rotate image until data is extracted from db
then
    display at another div id = display_db

unlock all divs
```

Comment: explain how would you do - "data is extracted from db" ? would you call a server side script on your server?

Comment: you need to provide more information - what exactly is the javascript code that puts the loading image in the div while the database information is pulled, and when does it remove the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you're looking for what is called a 'modal window'. 
this will add a layer above your page, blocking all mouse inputs to prevent further interaction with any elements during some time (e.g. until a 'OK' button is clicked or, as in your case, some server request has completed).

see the jQuery BlockUI Plugin for an example: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page